# Regex htaccess rewrite to strip url prefix

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

So many questions come close to it, but not quite there, and I'm afraid regex makes my head spin!

After a site recode, which slightly amended some urls - which we don't want to go 404 in Google, I am looking for a 301 redirect to remap:

http://www.oursite.com/listing-product-name-1234.html

to

http://www.oursite.com/product-name-1234.html

...you can see we just want to drop "listing-". The "1234" is a unique ID per product, and the product name can be multiple words (hyphen separated) by the way.

Thanks very much for the help regex heads!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^listing-(.+?\.html)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks very much, just the ticket :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}     ^/listing-(\w+-)+\d+\.html
RewriteRule     ^listing-(.*)      $1
```